# Retrieve the arn of a lambda function from a cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, metadata, aws-cloudformation

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve lambda function metadata during the cloudformation stack creation? We are looking to use the lambda function ARN to further build out other parts of the cloudformation template by storing it in an env variable.

Is this even possible? How do others reference arn when they are unknown until stack creation?

ed

Comment: To clarify... you wish to create other resources **in the same CloudFormation template** that refer to the Lambda function. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html), specifically `Fn::GetAtt` to get the lambda function's arn.

See: [Fn::GetAtt - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)

Comment: Thanks. That was what we were looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As per [this cheatsheet](https://theburningmonk.com/cloudformation-ref-and-getatt-cheatsheet/), you would use the following:

**json**

```
"MyFieldName": "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyLambdaFunc","Arn"]
```

**yaml**

```yaml
MyFieldName: !GetAtt MyLambdaFunc.Arn
```